# Finding the nearest neighbour K-NN

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Hey Guys I am having trouble with my code that creates 10 points, assigns a distance for each point between 1 and 500 and then finding the nearest two neighbours for each point. so far i have two classes my PointD class which is responsible for the math and assigning the neighbours and my main class which runs the program and calculates the distance:

PointD Class:

```
    package points;
/**
 *
 * @Ashley Caldwell
 */
public class PointD {
    private final int x;
    private final String name;
    //Creates an int named x for the math and a string called name for the point

    public PointD(int x, String name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.name = name;
    }//Used to create the Point

    public int distanceTo(PointD other) {
        return Math.abs(other.x - this.x);
    }//Math used to work out the distance to the next point

    /* extensions for your 2 neighbors */
    private PointD neighbor1 = null;
    private PointD neighbor2 = null;

    public String toString() {
        return  name +" "+ "at " + x + ", "
             + "with neighbors: " + (neighbor1 != null? neighbor1.name + 
             " Distance(" + distanceTo(neighbor1) + "), " : "") 
             + (neighbor2 != null? neighbor2.name + 
             " Distance(" + distanceTo(neighbor2) + ")" : ""); 
    }// sets the values to string for both the points

    public void setNeighbors(PointD p1, PointD p2) {
        neighbor1 = p1;
        neighbor2 = p2;
        //Assigns the neighbours to the point
    }

}
```

Main Class:

```
package points;
/**
 *
 * @Ashley Caldwell
 */
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {
 // better into a seperate MathLibrary
    public static int distance(PointD p1, PointD p2) {
        return p1.distanceTo(p2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        //used to create distances for points
        int numberOfPoints = 10+1;
        // generate points
        PointD[] points = new PointD[numberOfPoints];

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
            points[i] = new PointD(rng.nextInt(500) + 1, "Points " + i);

            //Loop assigns value between 1 and 500 to each point
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
            PointD currentPoint = points[i];
            PointD closestPoint = null;
            PointD secondClosestPoint = null;
            for(int j = 0; j < numberOfPoints; ++j) {
                if(i == j) continue;
                if(closestPoint == null || currentPoint.distanceTo(points[j]) < currentPoint.distanceTo(closestPoint)) {
                    secondClosestPoint = closestPoint;
                    closestPoint = points[j];
                } else if(secondClosestPoint == null || currentPoint.distanceTo(points[j]) < currentPoint.distanceTo(secondClosestPoint)) {
                    secondClosestPoint = points[j];
                }//Loop used to calculate the distance between each point by using current distance of point
            }
            currentPoint.setNeighbors(closestPoint, secondClosestPoint);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println(points[i]);

        }

    }// Prints out the points and the strings
}
```

This is the output when i run:

```
Points 0 at 80, with neighbors: Points 6 Distance(39), Points 3 Distance(40)
Points 1 at 212, with neighbors: Points 7 Distance(29), Points 9 Distance(64)
Points 2 at 308, with neighbors: Points 5 Distance(12), Points 8 Distance(19)
Points 3 at 40, with neighbors: Points 6 Distance(1), Points 0 Distance(40)
Points 4 at 489, with neighbors: Points 10 Distance(35), Points 8 Distance(162)
Points 5 at 296, with neighbors: Points 2 Distance(12), Points 9 Distance(20)
Points 6 at 41, with neighbors: Points 3 Distance(1), Points 0 Distance(39)
Points 7 at 241, with neighbors: Points 1 Distance(29), Points 9 Distance(35)
Points 8 at 327, with neighbors: Points 2 Distance(19), Points 5 Distance(31)
Points 9 at 276, with neighbors: Points 5 Distance(20), Points 2 Distance(32)
Points 10 at 454, with neighbors: Points 4 Distance(35), Points 8 Distance(127)
```

The main problem i am having is that some points are using the same points more than twice and so some points are not connected, i need to try and sort it so that it only finds two points which are closest and not already in use, the other problem i am having is that i want my Point 0 to be set to distance 0 at all times but do not know how to set the value for this element to zero as it is referencing another class, Having the distances random is not imperative and if it would be easier for me to change to have set values then i will do this but was just wondering if any one had any advice they could give?

Comment: I didn't understand the following at all, please rephrase: "some points are using the same points more than twice and so some points are not connected"

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clearer, Some points are finding the same point twice so for example in the output point 8 is nearest to point 2,4 and ten meaning that there are some points which are not neighbours with any of the other points, i am trying to create a network of points which all connect to  each other but by only having two connections to each point kind of like a tree diagram, hope this helps

Comment: As evident from the output, each point has exactly two neighbours, so there isn't any point that's not connected. For example, say you have 4 points A, B, C, D at respective  distances 1, 2, 3 and 10. Your algorithm would connect A to B, C; B to A, C; C to A, B; and D to C, B. How do you want A, B, C and D to be connected in this case?

Comment: from Point 0 I want that to connect to two points then each of them two points have two points of their own every time each point only having two points coming of it as i am trying to find the 2 nearest neighbours however in my code each point can have as many neighbours as it wants depending on the distance so i want to limit it so that points cant be used more than twice